# Barcode/QR Reader in Flex4.6?

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4, flash-builder, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for a barcode reader using a webcam in flash builder 4.6 for mobile application.   I have tried the following link [here](http://www.remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/adding-a-qr-code-reader-in-flex-on-android) but didnt work its showing “Nothing is decoded” If you tried to scan a Barcode/QR code using mobile device.  Please help me through some tutorials or examples or sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [LibSpark library](http://www.libspark.org/wiki/QRCodeReader/en)?

Comment: It works but it's not the quality similar to the zxing or zbar lib. The error detection is also not that strong, many times it produces characters that are not inside the QR-Code (strange characters).

Answer (score 0):

heve a look on actionscript implementation of zxing lib
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/actionscript

Comment: not as good as the original android code. I think it's code is out of date (not updated to the latest version). There is a great difference between the detection accuracy and performance of the AS3 version comparing to the android version. Does anybody know there is an ANE of the android version? I have also the ZBar solution for Windows and does the job very fast (can read almost everything) but there is no android code of it or am i wrong?